# Track member variable value change

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I want to track when a particular member variable changes value so I can print it out. Now, the obvious solution to do this is to add a tracking function in the member's `Set` method, like so :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}

    void SetBar(int value)
    {
        //Log that m_bar is going to be changed
        m_bar = value;
    }
private:
    int m_bar; // the variable we want to track
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm working on a huge project and some classes have a lot of methods that internally change member variables instead of calling their `Set`ters.

```
m_bar = somevalue;
```

Instead of :

```
SetBar(somevalue);
```

So I'm wondering if there's a faster/more clean method to achieve what I want than just changing every `m_bar =` to `SetBar(`. An assignment operator overload only for that member variable perhaps?

Comment: Is it for debugging? You can add data breakpoint for member variable address.

Comment: Change the data type into a wrapper for the actual data type, and in that wrapper define an appropriate `operator=`

Comment: You might want to lookup the [Observer Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Any solution short of making explicit calls would require a hack (as in "change type and add a conversion") or not be possible. One easy way to find out all spots where the variable is accessed would be to rename that variable, and see who screams.

Comment: That is what mutators are exactly for. They provide you the ability to add more logic besides just setting the value. It is reasonable to change the behaviour to use setters instead of directly changing the value.

Comment: There is no way to prevent member functions of a class or friends from directly accessing a private class member directly, David.   The only general solution is that mentioned by JSF - change the type of the variable in question so it does its own logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is possible for you to change the data type of the member, you can change it to a logger type.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Logger
{
  T value;

public:

  T& operator=(const T& other)
  {
    std::cout << "Setting new value\n";
    value = other;
    return value;
  }

  operator T() const
  {
    return value;
  }

};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}

    void SetBar(int value)
    {
        //Log that m_bar is going to be changed
        m_bar = value;
    }

private:

#if 1
    Logger<int> m_bar; // the variable we want to track
#else
    int m_bar; // the variable we want to track
#endif

};

int main()
{
  auto f = Foo();
  f.SetBar(12);
}
```

Online example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/oBBB8N).

Comment: Although if it's a big project, changing the data type might create complications and/or confusion in the long run. Changing the assignments to a setter might actually end up being worth it.

Comment: You can make this class behave like a value-type simply by overloading operators.